# Android data recovery

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen

Hi I really need help on this one, my Samsung j1 has a broken screen, it's just blank and gives no visual. When I connect it via USB my laptop recognizes it, but I can't access the data because I have a pattern lock on the screen (which is needed to unlock the phone before the computer allows access), and the screen is non-responsive to touch. Can anyone suggest any software or anything that'll help me recover my previous data? Please help. USB debugging isn't activated.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Looks like you've found the perfect tags for your question -- but might have missed the fact that our tags often also have wikis attached to them. Have you already checked with the "Data Recovery" section of our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info)? Or with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](/tags/data-recovery/info)? I bet you'll find your answer in the former.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately it didn't help me but I understand more now, I'll try the otg cable but here's to hoping I can get the unlock pattern somehow